# Can pysnmp return octectstring values only

Tags: pysnmp

I am doing a small script to get SNMP traps with PySnmp.

I am able to get the `oid = value pairs`, but the value is too long with a small information in the end. How can I **access the octectstring only** which comes in the end of the value. Is there a way other than string manipulations? Please comment.

> **OID =**_BindValue(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('value', ObjectSyntax------------------------------------------------(DELETED)-----------------(None, OctetString(b'**New Alarm**'))))

Is it possible to get the output like the following, as is available from another SNMP client:

> .iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.xxxx.1.1.2.2.14:  CM_DAS Alarm Traps:

Edit - the codes  are :

```
**for oid, val in varBinds:
      print('%s = %s' % (oid.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
      target.write(str(val))**
```

On screen, it shows short, but on file, the val is so long.

Usage of `target.write( str(val[0][1][2]))` does not work for all (program stops with error), but the 1st oid(time tick) gets it fine.

How can I get the value from tail as the actual value is found there for all oids.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMP transfers information in form of a sequence of OID-value pairs called variable-bindings:

```
variable_bindings = [[oid1, value1], [oid2, value2], ...]
```

Once you get the variable-bindings sequence from SNMP PDU, to access value1, for example, you might do:

```
variable_binding1 = variable_bindings[0]
value1 = variable_binding1[1]
```

To access the tail part of value1 (assuming it's a string) you could simply subscribe it:

```
tail_of_value1 = value1[-10:]
```

I guess in your question you operate on a single variable_binding, not a sequence of them.

If you want pysnmp to translate oid-value pair into a human-friendly representation (of MIB object name, MIB object value), you'd have to pass original OID-value pair to the [ObjectType](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType) class and run it through MIB resolver as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Please see the edit. Could you please correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...
the following codes works like somwwhat I was looking for.

```
            if str(oid)=="1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0":
                target.write(" = str(val[0][1]['timeticks-value']) = " +str(val[0][1]['timeticks-value'])) # time ticks

            else:
                target.write("= val[0][0]['string-value']= " + str(val[0][0]['string-value']))
```